# Localization of Gorenstein ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module, gorenstein

Let $R$ be a Gorenstein local ring and $S=R \setminus Z(R)$. *I want to prove* $S^{-1}R =⊕_{ht\ p=0} R_p$ and $S^{-1}R$ is injective $R$-module.
I can see the above $p$'s are minimal, $id_{R_p} R_p=0$ and $S^{-1}R =⊕_{htp=0} E(R/p)$.  And now?
thanks

Comment: Over a Noetherian ring, any direct sum of injective modules is injective (this in fact characterizes Noetherianness)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $R$ is Gorenstein, $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, so the minimal primes are exactly the associated primes. The localization maps $S^{-1}R \to R_p$ for $\text{ht}(p) = 0$ give a map $\displaystyle S^{-1}R \to \bigoplus_{\text{ht}(p)=0} R_p$, which is locally an isomorphism. Then note that $R_p$ is injective as an $R_p$-module, and thus (since injective hulls localize) also as an $R$-module, and direct sums of injectives over a Noetherian ring are again injective.

Comment: In this case the direct sum is finite, so there is no need to emphasize that the ring is noetherian.

Comment: @user26857: That's true. On the other hand, finiteness of the direct sum (among other facts in the problem) also follows from Noetherianness